# SpriteKit - SKCameraNode Parallax effect?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, parallax

I've been experimenting with SKCameraNode, but I can't find anything about creating a parallax effect with it.

Let's say I add to the code above and I add a `behindNode` below my `baseNode`.  Then I animate my camera.

```
let behindNode = SKNode()
addChild(behindNode)

let blueSquare = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.blueColor(), size: CGSize(width: 80, height: 80))
blueSquare.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2+40, y: size.height/2+40)
behindNode.addChild(blueSquare)

let baseNode = SKNode()
addChild(baseNode)

let redSquare = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.redColor(), size: CGSize(width: 80, height: 80))
redSquare.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2)
baseNode.addChild(redSquare)


let cameraNode = SKCameraNode()
camera = cameraNode
addChild(camera!)
camera!.position = redSquare.position

cameraNode.runAction(SKAction.sequence([
    SKAction.waitForDuration(1),
    SKAction.moveBy(CGVector(dx: 100, dy: 100), duration: 3),
    SKAction.moveBy(CGVector(dx: -100, dy: 100), duration: 1),
    SKAction.moveBy(CGVector(dx: 100, dy: -100), duration: 1)
]))
```

[image]

I need the blue square to move at a slower rate relative to the red square when the camera moves..  I would expect the cameranode to have a relative positions dictionary or something, but it doesn't..

Answer (score 4):

I created a solution that does not deal with seconds or frames.

You can create a subclass of SKCameraNode and use Swift's didSet() method that gets called after a class variable was changed. In our case we want to listen to the changes of the camera node's position variable.

```
class CameraNodeParallax:SKCameraNode{

override var position : CGPoint {
    didSet {  
       // Move our backgrounds
    }
}
```

We further want to create one array that contains all our parallax background nodes and one that contains the corresponding moving speed in relation to the camera's moving speed.

```
var backgroundNodes:[SKNode] = []
var backgroundNodesSpeedFactor:[CGVector] = [] // in relation to camera nodes speed

func addParallaxBackgroundNode(background:SKNode, vector:CGVector) {
    backgroundNodes.append(background)
    backgroundNodesSpeedFactor.append(vector)
}
```

A init() that fills our new variables might be useful as well

```
init(position:CGPoint) {
  super.init()
  self.position = position
}
```

Now we can fill our didSet() listener:

```
// Move our backgrounds
var i = 0
for node in backgroundNodes {

    let positionChangeX = position.x-oldValue.x
    let positionChangeY = position.y-oldValue.y
    let changeX = positionChangeX*backgroundNodesSpeedFactor[i].dx
    let changeY = positionChangeY*backgroundNodesSpeedFactor[i].dy
    node.position = CGPointMake(node.position.x+changeX,node.position.y+changeY)

    i += 1
}
```

The final code looks like this:

```
class CameraNodeParallax:SKCameraNode{

    var backgroundNodes:[SKNode] = []
    var backgroundNodesSpeedFactor:[CGVector] = [] // in relation to camera nodes speed

    init(position:CGPoint) {
        super.init()
        self.position = position
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override var position : CGPoint {
        didSet {

            // Move your parallax backgrounds
                var i = 0
                for node in backgroundNodes {

                    let positionChangeX = position.x-oldValue.x
                    let positionChangeY = position.y-oldValue.y
                    let changeX = positionChangeX*backgroundNodesSpeedFactor[i].dx
                    let changeY = positionChangeY*backgroundNodesSpeedFactor[i].dy
                    node.position = CGPointMake(node.position.x+changeX,node.position.y+changeY)

                    i += 1
                }
        }
    }

    func addParallaxBackgroundNode(background:SKNode, vector:CGVector) {
        backgroundNodes.append(background)
        backgroundNodesSpeedFactor.append(vector)
    }
}
```

I created an alternative implementation that does not inherit from SKCameraNode here https://github.com/gitmalong/lovelySpriteKitHelpers/blob/master/ParallaxBackgroundMover.swift

Answer (score 3):

I am using a parallax effect in my iOS 9 SpriteKit game.

Basically you're going to add a few lines of code to your scenes `update()` function that move the squares the opposite direction of the camera, BUT with some scaled factor.

```
update(){
  let moveXFactor: CGFloat = 3
  let moveYFactor: CGFloat = 2
  camera.position = CGPoint( camera.position.x + moveXFactor, camera.position.y + moveYFactor )

  let redSquareParallaxSpeedFactor: CGFloat = -0.2
  let blueSquareParallaxSpeedFactor: CGFloat = -0.1
  redSquare.position = CGPoint( redSquare.position.x + redSquareParallaxSpeedFactor * moveXFactor, redSquare.position.y + redSquareParallaxSpeedFactor * moveYFactor )
  blueSquare.position = CGPoint( blueSquare.position.x + blueSquareParallaxSpeedFactor * moveXFactor, blueSquare.position.y + blueSquareParallaxSpeedFactor * moveYFactor )
}
```

This is a simplified example. Use a variable that tracks the fps with a clock and moves objects based on a constant timescale, rather than one that is constantly going faster or slower based on the device's current fps.

So, define some variables in your scene's class file.

```
var lastUpdate: NSTimeInterval
var deltaTime: CGFloat
```

Then initialize them in the `init()` function of your scene's class.

```
lastUpdate = 0
deltaTime = 0.01666
```

And finally, update them every refresh in the `update()` function of your scene.

```
deltaTime = CGFloat( currentTime - lastUpdate )
lastUpdate = currentTime

if deltaTime > 1.0 {
  deltaTime = 0.0166
}
```

So now that this clock works, lets use it to scale the parallax effect so it's smoother.

```
update(){
  deltaTime = CGFloat( currentTime - lastUpdate )
  lastUpdate = currentTime

  if deltaTime > 1.0 {
    deltaTime = 0.0166
  }

  let someScale: CGFloat = 0.001

  var moveXFactor: CGFloat = 3 * deltaTime * someScale
  var moveYFactor: CGFloat = 2 * deltaTime * someScale
  camera.position = CGPoint( camera.position.x + moveXFactor, camera.position.y + moveYFactor )

  let redSquareParallaxSpeedFactor: CGFloat = -0.2
  let blueSquareParallaxSpeedFactor: CGFloat = -0.1
  redSquare.position = CGPoint( redSquare.position.x + redSquareParallaxSpeedFactor * moveXFactor, redSquare.position.y + redSquareParallaxSpeedFactor * moveYFactor )
  blueSquare.position = CGPoint( blueSquare.position.x + blueSquareParallaxSpeedFactor * moveXFactor, blueSquare.position.y + blueSquareParallaxSpeedFactor * moveYFactor )
}
```

Comment: thanks for all the code.  i was kinda hoping there was a more baked in way to do this.  skcameranode isnt really saving us much code.  might as well slide a bunch of sknodes around the old fashioned way

Comment: The idea is that you keep your game objects on the same level as the camera, and all background parallax objects use the code above.

Comment: How do you sort the z-order in this s that background objects never appear in front of foreground objects?

Comment: I get the general principle.. but I'm saying there really is no advantage to using SKCameraNode in this case.  If you're going to write all this code to move things around at different rates relative to the camera you may as well just slide some parent SKNodes around the old fashioned way..